# If a date is 22/12/2015 and has a value of 10, how to fill the value 10 to all the other dates following 22/12/2015 in qlikview?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have two tables `[ORDERS TABLE]` and `[PRICE LIST TABLE]`.

`[ORDERS TABLE]` contains the fields: `OrderDate`, `ItemCode`, `Quantity`.
`[PRICE LIST TABLE]` contains the fields: `Date`, `ItemCode`, `Price`.

Now the `[PRICE LIST TABLE]` explains the price of certain items during certain dates. It hardly consists of 10 - 15 records. For example:

```
Date       | ItemCode | Price
-----------+----------+----------
22/12/2015 | AB101    |    $95
27/12/2015 | AB101    |    $69
```

This means that the price has gone down for the same item AB101 on 27/12/2015. So the price of the item is 95$ during the dates 22/12/2015, 23/12/2015, 24/12/2015 ... 26/12/2015. On 27/12/2015, the price is 69$.

The `[ORDERS TABLE]` has the date of order, the `ItemCode` and the quantity for 22/12/2015, 23/12/2015, 24/12/2015 and so on.

**The problem:**
I want to add the field `Price` from the `[PRICE LIST TABLE]` to the `[ORDERS TABLE]`. But to do so, QlikView must assign the price of 95$ to the item between the period 22/12/2015 and 26/12/2015. Now 27/12/2015 has a change in price of 69$ for the same item as mentioned above. So the price of the item, on and after 27/12/2015 must be 69$ till another price change is specified. How do I do this?

If the price was specified for the item for every date in the `[PRICE LIST TABLE]`, then I can just join the two tables. But `[PRICE LIST TABLE]` only consist of the records where there has been a change in price. So I cannot merge the two tables based on the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there are one or two methods you could use: either populating a sparsely populated field (i.e. `Date` and `ItemCode`) or using `IntervalMatch`.

Here's some script for populating the fields. Normally, this is quite simple if you have only one field you wish to populate (i.e just `Date`), however, as you may have more than one `ItemCode` in your `[PRICE LIST TABLE]` then we must evaluate the date range for each of the unique `ItemCode`s in the table - easiest way to do this is through a loop that checks the range for each and populates accordingly.

In the below example, I took some of your sample data and created some inline tables to represent your source data, I also added a new `ItemCode` to demonstrate what happens if you have more than one in your price table with overlapping date ranges. Please note that this is probably not as optimised as it should be and there is probably a tidier way, but it works(!)

```
[PRICE LIST TABLE]:
LOAD 
    * 
INLINE [
    PricingDate, ItemCode, Price
    22/12/2015, AB101, 95
    27/12/2015, AB101, 69
    23/12/2015, AB102, 23
    29/12/2015, AB102, 43
];

TempTable_Pricing: 
NOCONCATENATE
LOAD
    PricingDate, 
    ItemCode,
    Price
RESIDENT [PRICE LIST TABLE];

DROP TABLE [PRICE LIST TABLE];

ItemList:
NOCONCATENATE
LOAD DISTINCT
    ItemCode
RESIDENT TempTable_Pricing;

FOR i = 0 to NoOfRows('ItemList') - 1

    LET item = peek('ItemCode',i,'ItemList');

    MinMaxDate:
    LOAD
        Min(PricingDate) as MinDate, 
        Max(PricingDate) as MaxDate
    RESIDENT TempTable_Pricing
    WHERE ItemCode = '$(item)';

    Let vMinDate = Peek('MinDate',-1,'MinMaxDate') - 1;
    Let vMaxDate = Peek('MaxDate',-1,'MinMaxDate')    ;

    JOIN (TempTable_Pricing)
    LOAD
        Date(recno()+$(vMinDate)) as PricingDate,
        '$(item)' as ItemCode
    AUTOGENERATE vMaxDate - vMinDate;

    PricingTable_Temp_$(i):
    NOCONCATENATE LOAD
        PricingDate as PricingDate_Temp, 
        if(isnull(ItemCode), peek(ItemCode), ItemCode) as ItemCode,
        if(isnull(Price), peek(Price), Price) as Price
    RESIDENT TempTable_Pricing
    ORDER BY ItemCode, PricingDate;

    DROP TABLE MinMaxDate;

    PricingTable:
    LOAD
        PricingDate_Temp as Date,
        ItemCode,
        Price
    RESIDENT PricingTable_Temp_$(i);

    DROP TABLE PricingTable_Temp_$(i);      

NEXT

DROP TABLE ItemList;
DROP TABLE TempTable_Pricing;

[ORDERS TABLE]:
NOCONCATENATE
LOAD
    date(OrderDate) as Date,
    ItemCode,
    Quantity
INLINE [
    OrderDate, ItemCode, Quantity
    22/12/2015, AB101, 1
    24/12/2015, AB101, 2
    27/12/2015, AB101, 4
    26/12/2015, AB102, 3
    29/12/2015, AB102, 1
];

INNER JOIN ([ORDERS TABLE])
LOAD
    Date,
    ItemCode,
    Price
RESIDENT PricingTable;

DROP TABLE PricingTable;
```

This results in the following table:

[image: An example of the resulting table]

Comment: Flawless. Works fine.